# Python Numba module gives me a wrong answer when using large numbers in computations

Tags: python, numba

When I run this code

```
from numba import jit
A,B,C,D = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
@jit()
def Z (A,B,C,D):
    X = (A**B)*(C**D)
    print(X)
    return X
Z(A, B, C, D)
```

If I enter values of `"2887969 614604076030 8478041 209676100616"` it returns `0` and that's not right.

Comment: That's a HUGE number. Do you know what answer you expect?

Comment: Not sure why you're surprised.  That first half (A**B) has 4 trillion digits and would require 1.6TB of memory to store.  You need to use common sense.  You can do that kind of computation in modulo arithmetic, but not in integer or floating point.

Comment: Those are very large numbers, if the type is supposed to be an int, it will overflow. You can check the type signature with Z.inspect_types()

Comment: @TimRoberts it wouldn't take that much memory to store, it is just a number representation...

Comment: @Wade I don't know what you mean.  That number requires 13 trillion bits.  How do you plan to "represent" it without using 13 trillion bits?

Comment: @TimRoberts you could use sign + mantissa if these were floats, but that would still overflow a standard float64. I think the point for the person asking is that there are overflow limits for different types when using Numba.

Comment: This is actually unrelated to Numba.  The limits are the same for standard Python or for Numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for integer representations for numbers, there are upper and lower limits of what can be represented.

In the type signature below, you can see that when I enter these numbers, the compiler assigns A and C to 32 bit integers (max value of around 2 billion) and B and D to 64 bit integers (max value of 1.84 * 10^19).

X is also a 64 bit integer, but the number you are trying to represent is far too large for it to contain, so it will not return accurate results.

You can view the types the compilers assigns with `<function name>.inspect_types()`, or in your case `Z.inspect_types()`.

```
Z (int32, int64, int32, int64)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# File: C:\Users\wade.roberts\PycharmProjects\workspace\numba_workspace.py
# --- LINE 6 --- 

@jit()

# --- LINE 7 --- 

def Z(A, B, C, D):

    # --- LINE 8 --- 
    # label 0
    #   A = arg(0, name=A)  :: int32
    #   B = arg(1, name=B)  :: int64
    #   C = arg(2, name=C)  :: int32
    #   D = arg(3, name=D)  :: int64
    #   $0.3 = A ** B  :: int64
    #   del B
    #   del A
    #   $0.6 = C ** D  :: int64
    #   del D
    #   del C
    #   X = $0.3 * $0.6  :: int64
    #   del $0.6
    #   del $0.3

    X = (A ** B) * (C ** D)

    # --- LINE 9 --- 
    #   $0.8 = global(print: <built-in function print>)  :: Function(<built-in function print>)
    #   del $0.8
    #   print(X)
    #   $0.10 = const(NoneType, None)  :: none
    #   del $0.10

    print(X)

    # --- LINE 10 --- 
    #   $0.12 = cast(value=X)  :: int64
    #   del X
    #   return $0.12

    return X
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out, that in python an integer can be arbitrary large and this is the reason the result could be right in pure python if there were enough memory available.